# mysql query to show count of distinct result

Tags: php, mysql

i have three tables , i want to combine the output of three result and show the result here is my table structure and query

table_campaign   - ID is auto increment

```
id         banner                views_left     packages

1          A1                       555                5
2          A1                       527                5
3          B1                       580                98
4          C1                       293                69
```

table_packages-Id is auto increment

```
id      name    special     
1       India       IND
2       Aus         Australia 
3       Pak         Pakistan
```

tablepage       (uri &  banner in table_campaign are same)

```
 id     uri     views   
 1      A1       54
 2      B1       94
 3      C1       38
```

i want to check the sum of all banner of similar type in 
table_campaign and will check with tablepage and if the total views in table_campaign is less than tablepage views then it will display the result.

i have tried three independent queries. can you please guide how to write so that if views in tablepage is less than combined view of views_left column of table_campaign it will show the result or it will not show any result. i want to dispaly random result out of several which satisfies this criteria

```
$res23 = sql_query("SELECT sum(views_left) as num from table_campaign where banner!='{$client['uri']}'  " );
    $row23 = sql_fetch_array($res23);
    $stats['views_left'] = $row23['num'];


$res = sql_query("SELECT * from `table_packages` where special='{$client['location']}'");
$row = sql_fetch_array($res);
$packages=$row['id'];
{



$res2 = sql_query("SELECT * from `table_campaign` banner  where packages='{$packages}' order by  views_left   desc limit 4");{
while($row = sql_fetch_array($res2)) {
$banner1= $row['banner'];
$views_left = $row['views_left'];
$output4 .= '<table width="100%"><tr><td style="text-align:left;"><a href="'.$banner1.'">'.$banner1.'</a></td><td style="text-align:right;">'.$views_left.'  '.$stats['views_left'].'</td></tr></table>
';}

ass(array('title'=>t('abc'), 'content' => '<div class="toolbar">'.'<div style="border:0px solid #B2BCA7;margin-bottom:20px;"><div style="padding: 7px; position: relative;">'.$output4.'</div>'));
}
```

i simply wanted to show this content

sum of table_campaign summation of view left from all row minus tablepage view

my tablepage uri column and table_campaign banner column is same .but in tablepage the uri column is unique and  it can appear only once but in table_campaign banner column can come several times so i want to add the views_left of all row from table_campaign and compare with tablepage views column .if views column for that particular uri is more than sum of views_left column it will display the output as i have shown . i think  i am very clear now

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far

Comment: Perhaps you could start by showing us the queries you have tried, and what is wrong with them?

Comment: @Steeve:  Thanks for that.  I appreciate you've described what output you're after, but perhaps you could show the desired output of a concrete example?

Comment: @EGGYAL UPDATED THE CODE PLEASE CHECK LAST PARAGRAPH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would write it:

```
SELECT sum(table_campaign.views_left) - tablepage.views  FROM table_campaign,tablepage where tablepage.uri=table_campaign.banner group by table_campaign.banner;
```

Comment: without any join statement?????/// its giving  output but i think its adding all rows without filtering as its giving huge number and i want to list 5-6 rows randomly but its giving only one output with all row added result